# Cassandra loss of a node

Tags: cassandra, cluster-computing

I'm trying to figure out, how to parameter my 2 nodes cluster, in order to have an exact replica, if one of them is down...
using this tools to check it out : http://www.ecyrd.com/cassandracalculator/

For the following parameters :

```
Cluster size: 2 / Replication Factor: 2 / Write Level: All / Read Level: One
```

it gives me the results :

- Your reads are **consistent**
- You can survive the loss of **no nodes**.
- You are really reading from **1 node every time**.
- You are really writing to **2 nodes every time**.
- Each node holds **100%** of your data.

I agree with all those result except one, "You can survive the loss of no nodes".
I don't get why the cluster can't survive from one node loss, if one dies, the "Write: ALL" will write to the only one node left, doesn't it ?
Then when I bring back up the second node, it should synchronize with the 1st, and accept writes again, doesn't it ?

If I'm wrong, can someone explain to me why ?

EDIT :

More Configuration will give me the same results except for the holding %:

```
Cluster size: 3 / Replication Factor: 2 / Write Level: All / Read Level: One
Cluster size: 3 / Replication Factor: 2 / Write Level: Quorum / Read Level: One
```

Even if I try to be consistent with Reads, and not Writes :

```
Cluster size: 2 / Replication Factor: 2 / Write Level: One / Read Level: Quorum
```

Every time it tells me that I can't suffer the loss on any node.

Comment: A cluster of just 2 nodes is very unusual in real production Cassandra deployments. RF 3 is much more common b/c it allows quorum reads and writes with the loss of one node.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because of the replication factor

> *When replication factor exceeds the number of nodes, writes are rejected, but reads are served as long as the desired consistency
>   level can be met.*

Source : http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/cluster_architecture/replication

Comment: So how can you configure the Cassandra cluster in order to do what OP wants it to do?

Comment: We can try by setting the Consistency level to ONE.

Comment: If I read correctly the Datastax quote, reads are served, So I put Writes to One and Reads to Qorum, it should give me the ability to suffer a loss of one node ? The tools says it won't. I have edited my question for more configurations

Comment: Case :  Write : ONE ,Read : Quroum. Qourum = (replication_factor / 2) + 1 so in this case (2/2)+1=2 node.That means both the nodes need to  be up for reading.

Comment: I though the Qorum was about the number of nodes live, not the Replication Factor, thank you for theses infos.

Answer (score 0):

> I agree with all those result except one, "You can survive the loss of
>   no nodes". I don't get why the cluster can't survive from one node
>   loss, if one dies, the "Write: ALL" will write to the only one node
>   left, doesn't it ? Then when I bring back up the second node, it
>   should synchronize with the 1st, and accept writes again, doesn't it ?
>
> If I'm wrong, can someone explain to me why ?

This isn't how consistency works. When a node goes down Cassandra doesn't forget about it when working out QUORUM. Your replication factor is 2 and thus ALL is 2 and as soon as one node is down you are down for writes.

If you need read consistency (be sure that you do). Then try a 3 node cluster with a RF of 3 then read and write at QUORUM. This means you can now handle a node down for reads and writes.

For you last example:

> Cluster size: 2 / Replication Factor: 2 / Write Level: One / Read Level: Quorum

QUORUM = RF / 2 + 1 = 2 so what is why you are down.

In general you want an odd RF for QUORUM systems.